# Google Event DateTime to System DateTime & vice versa C#

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I need to convert convert Google Event DateTime (In Google Calendar) to System DateTime & vice versa in C# . Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Event Datetime apparently uses RFC3339 DateTime, so to convert it to System.Datetime, you can use:

```
XmlConvert.ToDateTime(string s, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode dateTimeOption)
```

To convert from System.Datetime to Google Datetime, do:

```
XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode dateTimeOption)
```

Comment: Can you give me an example plz?

Comment: @ThanujaDilhan, for example, `XmlConvert.ToDateTime("2002-10-02T15:00:00Z", XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Local)` will convert 2002-10-02T15:00:00Z to the local System.DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

The Datetime has the following constructor:

```
DateTime time = new DateTime(year, mounth, day, hour, minute, second);
```

It may serve for the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't use Umut Seven's advice. But I tried to make it simple as Sandro Z. said. It became a little bit childish :) but there may be someone like me, so here is my code:

```
#region Googlestuff
var service = new CalendarService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    ApiKey = "xxxx",
    ApplicationName = "xxxx",
});
EventsResource.ListRequest lr = service.Events.List(calendarID);
#endregion

List<DateTime> starts = new List<DateTime>();    
foreach (var myEvent in lr.Execute().Items)
{
    string start = myEvent.Start.DateTime.ToString(); //it gives something like "11.09.2017 09:30:00"
    starts.Add(new DateTime(
    Convert.ToUInt16(start.Split(' ')[0].Split('.')[2]), //takes year
    Convert.ToUInt16(start.Split(' ')[0].Split('.')[1]), //takes month
    Convert.ToUInt16(start.Split(' ')[0].Split('.')[0]), //takes day
    Convert.ToUInt16(start.Split(' ')[1].Split(':')[0]), //takes hour
    Convert.ToUInt16(start.Split(' ')[1].Split(':')[1]), //takes minute
    Convert.ToUInt16(start.Split(' ')[1].Split(':')[2]))); //takes second
}
Console.WriteLine(starts);
```